# Optimization of Person table with FirstName, SecondName and LastName

Tags: database, database-normalization

Consider the table below (in MS SQL syntax):

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName nvarchar(32),
    SecondName nvarchar(32),
    LastName nvarchar(32)
)
```

let assume the table has 100 000 000 rows, but there are only 100 distinct first names and second names.

Does it make a sense to move FirstName and SecondName to a separate table with INT id like this?

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstNameId INT,
    SecondNameId INT,
    LastName nvarchar(32)
)

CREATE TABLE FirstName (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName nvarchar(32),
)

CREATE TABLE SecondName (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    SecondName nvarchar(32),
)
```

1) Does this separation save the space on the disk?

2) Does it optimizes the search by FirstName and SecondName (comparing the the original Person table with created indices)?

3) Does it relate to the normalization somehow? What version of Person table does meet the normal form requirements?

4) What is the common practice? Is this done in the real-world databases?

Answer (score 0):

1) `INT` is a 32-bit integer. I would guess most `FirstName` and `LastName` entries are more than four characters, so with 100,000,000 rows, you might see some savings.

2) In a relational database, you're going to be writing the `id` column from `Person` in any other tables that may hold some more detailed information about a given `Person`. If you're going to frequently be querying the `Person` table directly (e.g looking for FirstNames for a given LastName), you might want to put an index on the column(s) you're going to be looking up by. It's not going to help you with any `JOIN` since you'll be joining to the primary key

3) As with the answer above, you're going to be writing the `id` column to other tables that will hold more info about a given `Person`. Since your `Person` table only contains info about `Person`, you're on track for normalization

4) I can't imagine you would be doing many queries by `FirstName` or `SecondName`. I imagine that you would more likely be doing a `JOIN` from a related table, for which the primary key is what matters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, yes, yes and yes even if out of 100 000 000 rows there are 100 000 diff values. 
However this practice does not allow free text. If a 'Johnnie' prefers his name like 'Johnie' for any reason you need to accommodate that with some lookup data-add mechanism, assuming those tables are used for data entry. And when you do that, then you cannot prevent lazy users where wrong name which will turn into a real entry into your system. Because another 'Johnnie' will enter 'Johnnir' (press r for e) so you now have 3 names to your look-ups!